# How do the emergency doors on the Enterprise refit work?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise

In *Wrath of Khan*, during the first strike, we see various emergency doors closing on in engineering. One of these appears to bisect part of the warp core. Is this merely an oversight of the production crew?

[image: Door closing on the warp core]

[image: Door bisecting the core]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [*Mr Scott's Guide to the [refit] Enterprise*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Scott%27s_Guide_to_the_Enterprise) factbook, the feature you're describing is the "**[horizontal intermix chamber](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Intermix_chamber)**".

The Vertical Chamber (the centre of which is located in Main Engineering) provides power for the impulse engines and ship systems. The Horizontal Chamber, which starts in Main Engineering and extends backwards through the ship, provides power for the warp engines. Both chambers are linked, but can operate independently for a time, hence why an emergency door can bisect this feature to prevent a radiation leak from the vertical core stopping them going to warp or a radiation leak from the horizontal core stopping them using impulse and/or losing power for torpedoes and shields.

> Located in the center of the room, and extending for many levels both
>   above and below the deck, is the vertical linear intermix chamber.
>   This complex, radically new design in intermix technology provides
>   operational power for the impulse drive system and furnishes enough
>   additional energy to power all other shipboard systems. Both matter
>   and antimatter for the chamber are contained in a series of magnetic
>   bottles, which are housed in pods at the base of the intermix shaft.
>   These pods may be ejected from the ship in case of extreme emergency
>   via two large blow-away panels in the outer hull.
>
> E**xtending aftward from the vertical shaft is a horizontal chamber
>   which draws its matter/antimatter fuel from the same source. This
>   shaft provides source energy for the warp field nacelles and phaser
>   banks. The linear configuration has proven to be consistently cooler,
>   cleaner, and more efficient than any other system in use today.**

Comment: If an emergency door appears to bisect part of the warp core that might easily be explained by the 'door' being a finely-shaped force-field but however correct, how does any of the detail in that response address, let alone Answer the Question?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - Well, for starters it explains that this isn't the warp core, but in fact another feature entirely.

Comment: And secondly, it explains that having a door pass through one of the two intermix chambers isn't an oversight, it's a necessary safety procedure

Comment: What are you Posting about? What suggests this isn't the warp core but another feature, and how?

Having a door pass through (anything) might be a necessary safety procedure but why is it OK to ignore how that might come about?

How will you make your door 'pass through' anything, instead of using my finely-shaped force-field to perfectly butt up against every aspect of - in this case - the warp core?

Comment: "What suggests this isn't the warp core but another feature, and how?" - "***Extending aftward from the vertical shaft is a horizontal chamber which draws its matter/antimatter fuel from the same source."***

Comment: Thanks and if that was a clear as you thought it was, how could it address the fact that though having a door pass through (anything) might be a necessary safety procedure, how that might be brought about still matters? How will you make your door 'pass through' anything, instead of using my finely-shaped force-field to perfectly butt up against every aspect of - in this case - the warp core?